# getting store uuid eats API

Tags: javascript, node.js, store, uuid, uber-api

How could I find stores uuid with a simple request. I usually just go on the web page and then take it from developer tools. But now I'd like, by a script (in JS), to just need to write the name of the store and then the uuid would be displayed. I need it for my Eats App. Thanks !

Comment: If you show us here in your question how you manually get it from the web page (show an actual web page example), then perhaps we could help you automate that.  But, without that example, we have no idea what you're trying to do.  Don't even know what a "store uuid" is or where it comes from or what system its part of.

Comment: The store uuid is the id attached only to that store. The way I access it today is, by going on the uber eats page, opening developer tools from your browser (mine is firefox), then go to network. Then, you click on the store you want, and look in the network field for a request named like GetStoreV1 or something like this. You will be able to find the store uuid this way.